# Which access-date should be used for cited websites

Tags: citations, ethics, citation-style

As the title says I am wondering which access date I should use for citing a website.

Let's say the assignment is due in one week and I have cited and accessed the website one month ago. Now I am revisiting the website to look for changes/new information only to find that nothing changed since my last visit. Which date should I choose as access date?

I think it would be nice to use the most recent date to show that the information is recent/still valid, however I think more recent dates could be frowned upon as it looks like I just recently started working on the assignment altogether.

If it matters: The field is Computer Science

Comment: Why would anyone conclude that the date was when you started, as opposed to last-minute due diligence?  And why would anyone care whether you started late, as long as you submit a good report on time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very little that could have changed between your first access and your most recent one. Access dates are used for material that is likely to have changed rapidly. In this case I would use your first access date, i.e. the oldest one, unless you are using material that you *know* wasn't there on the older date. If you do that, use the date you found that material.